# Is there an option to paste the formula in Office 365?

Tags: excel

I want to add Paste Formulas, but there is no Paste Formulas option in all commands in customize the quick access Toolbar

Version 2208 Office 365

Comment: What's wrong with a simple "Paste"?

Comment: Are you referring to pasting to excel on the web?

Comment: I want to use formula paste and I don't work on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?  
(*You may have to click on the image to see it clearly in a new window*)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, I really don't understand what's wrong with a regular paste, as you can see from this screenshot:

[image]

In cell "A2", I had put the value 36.
In cell "B2", I had put the formula `=A2*A2`.

In cell "A5", I have put the value 49.
In cell "B5", I copy the content of cell "B2" into "B5", using regular "Paste", and I get the formula pasted and adapted to the other cell's coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was looking for the option to paste  formulas in Quick access toolbar. At first, I was searching by pasting  formulas, but with our friend's answer, I realized that I should look for it in the formulas.